Error 400 en solicitud flutter
Estoy haciendo un registro de usuario desde flutter el cuál envía una solicitud a una api hecha en django. Lo raro es que al probar en postman, la api funciona sin ningún problema, pero al intentar hacer el registro desde la app, este genera el error 400. Paso código:
FLUTTER:
Future<void> registrarUsuario() async {
final url = 'https://tfg-admin.onrender.com/api/register/';
final response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse(url),
  body: jsonEncode({
    'ci': int.tryParse(_ciController.text) ?? 0,
    'username': _nombreUsuarioController.text,
    'first_name': _nombreController.text,
    'last_name': _apellidoController.text,
    'email': _emailController.text,
    'password': hashPassword(_contrasenaController.text), // Codifica la contraseña
  }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
);
if (response.statusCode == 201) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      content: Text(
        'Registro Exitoso',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    ),
  );
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      content: Text(
        'Error al registrar usuario: ${response.statusCode}',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    ),
  );
}

}
DJANGO:
def api_register(request):
serializer = UsuarioSerializer(data=request.POST)
if serializer.is_valid():
    usuario = serializer.save(password=request.POST['password'])
    usuario.set_password(usuario.password)  # Hashear la contraseña antes de guardarla
    usuario.save()
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

EL SERIALIZER:
class UsuarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Usuario
    fields = ['ci', 'username','first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']
    # Oculta la contraseña en la respuesta
    extra_kwargs = {
        'password': {'write_only': True}
    }

Destaco que es la primera vez que hago una api.
